# UML: packages within packages

Tags: package, uml, aggregation, composition

I am working on a UML package diagram, and was wondering: a lot of my packages have a related topic in common, so i put them into a more general package.  When drawing the UML diagram, do I literally draw the packages within a larger package?  Or, do I use the aggregate/composition arrow to denote that the larger/more-general package contains them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML has a containment relationship you can use. It's a line with the end nearest the containing package having a symbol like (+). It is also valid to draw concentric packages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Violet UML Editor allows putting packages within packages, so I'm going to assume that's an acceptable way to do this, unless somebody can convince me otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Although UML has the nesting relation it is much more common to show the containment in diagrams by simply enlarge the containing package and place the contained one inside.

The containment from my POV is superfluous as the physical containment can as well be represented by nesting packages. If you look on p. 111 of Superstructures 2.1.1 you see an example of both representations.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions: Make sure that you have separated your package content sufficiently.  Perhaps there is another organization that doesn't have package inclusion.  Second, you can use dependency relationships allowing multiple packages to be dependent on the functionality of another package.